# PATH command not found

Tags: environment-variables

I'm not experienced with PATH (Any good reference would be appreciated), but I made a mistake and did `PATH=/google_appengine`, which I'm assuming completely overrid PATH.

Still, I restarted bash and echo'd PATH and found that the folders were back.

> mark@mark-laptop:~$ echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

However, when I then tried to append to it, I got an error that PATH wasn't found. I've looked around Google and couldn't find a good answer. Any help would be appreciated

> mark@mark-laptop:~$ PATH = $PATH:/google_appengine
>   PATH: command not found

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mustn't use spaces around `=`, so it should look like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/google_appengine
```